# Learning CoreLocation for IOS7 based on The Big Nerd Ranch Guide

Tags: ios7, xcode5, cllocationmanager

hi im learning coreLocation for IOS7  with xcode 5. im referencing to the big nerd ranch guide edition 3. i am using the iphone retina(3.5 inch) simulator.

i am on chapter 4, retrieving updates from CLLocationManager (i.e: whereami). the objective of this topic is to learn about CLLocationManager, delegates, and to retrieve the current location.

i am stuck because when i run the simulator, i am supposed to see the location of the object in my console which will look something like this. :

```
<+37.33168900, -122.03073100> +/- 100.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00)
```

i am not getting the above results. i have set the simulated location to london, england. on the book it says i should be giving some permission for the application to use location services on the device, but im not getting any on the simulator. i also notice that under log navigator, the Debug is still loading. And in Debug navigator, the memory keeps increasing. I tried setting breakpoints in WhereamiViewController.m but the program doesn't reach anywhere in here. i then set in main.m and tried to do a step into on the following line of code but it just stepped over:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([WhereamiAppDelegate class]));
```

here are my codes:

**WhereamiViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@end
```

**WhereamiViewController.m**

```
#import "WhereamiViewController.h"

@implementation WhereamiViewController

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        // Create location manager object
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        // There will be a warning from this line of code; ignore it for now
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];

        // And we want it to be as accurate as possible
        // regardless of how much time/power it takes
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

        // Tell our manager to start looking for its location immeidately
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find locatoin:%@", error);
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    // Tell the location manager to stop sending us messages
    [locationManager setDelegate:nil];
}
@end
```

**main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "WhereamiAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([WhereamiAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

i am very new in this so any help in pointing out the right direction i should take will be much appreciated =)

Comment: Can you share the code from `AppDelegate.m`?

Comment: hi i have found my solution. i will post it below

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution at http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=216&t=4514#p20666

only if i have look abit harder.

Xcode5 uses storyboard. so it will not call initWithNib. to get it working, i replaced `(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` with the following

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        [locationManager setDelegate:self];

        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
}
```

in iOS7, didUpdateToLocation: fromLocation is deprecated and replaced with didUpdateLocations. replace with the following:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[locations lastObject]);
}
```

I tested and it is working now.